# How to open an image in VB6 and make it fullscreen

Tags: vb6

I have been trying to open an image in VB6 using 2 picture boxes and scaling width and height to the size of the screen.

Is there any way to open the image in a way that wont show the Start command of windows on the bottom and the name of the window on the top?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can have the form run in maximized mode. And make the form border style to none to hide the title bar.

For Hiding / Overlaying the Task Bar of Windows, you can refer to [This Post from VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?483893-RESOLVED-VB6-Make-program-cover-the-taskbar)

A preview of the code used is as below:

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long,_
ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, _
ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0
Private Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1
Private Const HWND_TOP = 0
Private Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40

Private Sub Form_Load()
'This code will maximize the window covering the task bar
   Dim ll_Width As Long
   Dim ll_Height As Long

If Me.WindowState = vbMaximized Then
    WindowState = vbNormal
End If

'work out full screen dimensions
ll_Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
ll_Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

'use SetWindowPos to resize window
Call SetWindowPos(Me.hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ll_Width, _
    ll_Height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
End Sub
```